# Rails select has_many though get the right Id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

[image][image]I'm trying to pass the size of a product to a order with select. the product has many sizes with has_many though.
the size.id on the orger page did not match with the size.id that i choose on the product page.
someone know why?

> for exemple if choose product size.id(2) on the order page show size.id(4)

**Size Model**

```
 attr_accessible :size
  has_many :orders 
  has_many :sizeship
  has_many :products, :through => :sizeship
```

**Product Model**

```
 has_many :orders
  has_many :sizeships
  has_many :sizes, through: :sizeships
```

**Order Model**

```
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product, touch: true
  belongs_to :size
```

**Cart Model**

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :orders
```

**Product Controller**

```
def show
   @product = Product.cached_find(params[:id])

  @sizes_for_dropdown = @product.sizes.collect { |s| [s.size, s.id] }

end
```

**Cart Controller**

```
 def add
    product = Product.find(params[:id])

    if product
     if product.buyable?(current_user)
        current_user.cart = Cart.new #if current_user.cart.nil?
        size =  product.sizes.find_by_id(params[:size_id])
        quantity = params[:quantity].to_i > 0 ? params[:quantity].to_i : 1
       order = current_user.cart.orders.find_by_product_id_and_status_and_size_id(product.id, nil, product.sizes.nil? ? nil : product.sizes.find { |l| l.id } )

        if order.nil? # create new order
          order = Order.new
          order.product = product
          order.size = product.sizes.find { |k| k.id } 

          current_user.cart.orders << order
        else # increase quantity
          order.quantity += quantity
          order.save
        end

        redirect_to product_path(product)
        flash[:success] = "Success"
      else
        redirect_to product_path(product)
        flash[:error] = " Error"

      end
    else
      redirect_to :shop, flash[:error] = 'Error'
    end
  end
```

**Log**

```
Started POST "/carts/add/yy" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-17 00:11:16 -0200
Processing by CartsController#add as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Hf7eLJPojw+u/HCGuQtAVzADC7v0jpkw5mJ0sCmx0u4=", "score"=>"", "quantity"=>"1",  "size_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"add to basket", "id"=>"yy"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/yy
Completed 302 Found in 3471.4ms
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Thanks for putting up all the relevant code, it really helps. I'm still a bit unsure of what's actually going wrong though - can you give an example of what you mean by "the wrong one"? can you show us some example data, and what you'd expect to see, but what you're seeing instead?

Comment: thank you for interest @TarynEast, i edited my question. i mean the size.id that show on the order page did not match the size.id that i choose on the product page

Comment: Hi great - but that's not enough for us to go on. Can you give us some sample data - ie what's inside of product with the id of 2 and what's there for product with id 4? How do you choose them what code do you use to choose them? what is the size that you're getting (show us) and what size do you expect (show us, don't tell). Also: you mention "the order page" - but haven't shown us that :)

Comment: right i'll post a screen!

Comment: right, on the screen if i choose M on the order show GG

Comment: Rather than a screen-grab... can you please show us the actual code you use to generate that drop-down? It's hard to debug a screen-grab :)
Also - we really do need to see an example of the actual data. It would also be most useful would be to see what params are coming through-  you can look in your console-window or logfile (`log/development.log`) to find the line that shows the Params that are passed when you click "submit" - this is the kind of thing that will actually help us figure out where the bug is.

Comment: Once we know what data is passed to your controller - then we can look at what the controller is doing with that data to make the incorrect choice... and then we can suggest what you need to change in your form to be passing the right data.

Comment: right! thank you @TarynEast! i edited the question

Comment: ok so my first idea is: `yy` is not really an id... certainly not a standard Rails id (which is usually an integer) or a `guid` - so what is `yy` supposed to be? Perhaps you have non-standard ids for finding the correct product - and it's not actually finding the correct product (which would then find this other product's sizes). Can you give mt the example of data I suggested? eg in your controller, add the line `puts "product: #{product.inspect}` after you first instantiate the product. also add `puts "size: #{product.sizes.inspect}` - then hit submit show us what appears in the terminal

Comment: hello @TarynEast. the yy id issue is because of the friendly_id gem. to show the name of the product on the browser. ok i'll check!

Comment: there is:


product: #<Product id: 2, slug: "yy", name: "yy", detail: "dedede", size_id: nil,  quantity: 33, created_at: "2016-11-16 06:16:56", updated_at: "2016-11-17 04:05:09">
size: [#<Size id: 3, size: "GG", created_at: "2016-08-16 02:38:12", updated_at: "2016-08-16 02:38:12">, #<Size id: 2, size: "M", created_at: "2016-08-16 02:38:12", updated_at: "2016-08-16 02:38:12">, #<Size id: 1, size: "P", created_at: "2016-08-16 02:38:12", updated_at: "2016-08-16 02:38:12">]

Comment: ok, so according to the params that come through (with a size_id of '1') you should end up with the `<Size id: 1, size: "P", created_at: "2016-08-16 02:38:12", updated_at: "2016-08-16 02:38:12">` being picked out by the line `size =  product.sizes.find_by_id(params[:size_id])`. *however* I notice you aren't *using* `size` anywhere, you just throw it away. Then use this: `product.sizes.find { |l| l.id }` and when setting up a new order you have: `order.size = product.sizes.find { |k| k.id }` so... which is the correct way to select a size? Maybe just use `size` instead?